# Every website on the server redirects to a foreign page, even after clean install

Tags: nginx, centos, security, redirect

First of all, this is my first time posting here, so sorry if I posted in the wrong section.

To get to the point:
I have a CentOS 7 + Gnome server, with VestaCP configured and running 2 WordPress websites. Last week, I noticed that they went offline, and I couldn't SSH into the server. When I physically logged onto the server, I noticed that everything was redirecting to a single page, where it said that the website was under maintenance.

The curious thing about it is that the page contained the text

> this is 1stweb.de

If I access that page, I get the exact same thing.

What I did:

- restored backups from when everything was working;
- reconfigured the `.htaccess` file of the websites;
- reinstalled VestaCP;
- did a fresh install of the OS, Vesta and restoring the backups.

Even after all this, I get the same result.

What made me even more curious is that when I inspect the page I'm thrown at, I notice two things:
- it loads an image from *mydomain.com*/website-under-maintenance.png, which doesn't exist;
- inspecting the network request made when accessing any of the websites, I see this:

> this is 1stweb.de website-under-maintenance TRANSFERRING NANOMITES TO
>   YOUR COMPUTER

If I search for that page on Google, I don't get anything that looks related to it.

Is there anything that I missed? I don't have a lot of experience, so I may have did something wrong, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot find the files that it is loading in your web directory, there could be a problem of someone pointing your DNS to their server in order to hijack your traffic. I would start with verifying your DNS, and after that is made sure to point to the correct place, try running a new installation of wordpress with just a default page to see if it happens again.

Comment: Same thing happens with a new wordpress instalation. Changed resolv.conf to contain Google's nameservers, hope that will fix it.

Comment: @Vlad Also check with whoever you purchased the domain from and make sure that their DNS record for your domain name (A record) is pointed to the IP address that you have.

Comment: @VladGhiurea:  As suggested, check the IP returned by looking up your host name.

Comment: Check your domains from another PC. If they are looking like a should, check your hosts file. There is could be entries for your domains pointing to another IP.

Comment: After resetting the nameservers on the registrar's website, everything is finally working as it should. Thank you for the help!